# Multicolored Mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, add-on

I know about the ability to change the color of an object in **Edit Mode**. Is it possible to change the color of individual polygons of an object in **Edit Mode**? For example, I give an illustration of the Topology of the Head with the main lines marked. This would be helpful in modeling. Perhaps there is some kind of addon? Blender version 3.0.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by setting different materials to the faces. To do so, create several materials, and set different viewport display colors:

[image]

Then select the faces that you want to color:

[image]

Select different material and press assign:

[image]

You'll get like this:

[image]

If not, check if you are in solid mode and Color → Material is selected:

[image]

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot!